# C++:Error: unable to create variable object at stl_list.h

Tags: c++, list, object, variables

I have this:

My includes

```
#include<iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
```

Where it crashes:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++){
    Actual = SPLITaVecINT(txtvec[i+1]);
    max = Actual.size(); 
    if (max != 1) {
        for (k = 0; k < porte; k++) {
            Grf.addEdge(Actual[0], Actual[k+1]); //**HERE IT CRASHES**
        }
    }
}
Grf.bridge();
```

addEdge is here, its using double-linked lists.

```
void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w);
    adj[w].push_back(v);  // Note: the graph is undirected
}
```

So while debugging in CLion, it goes to stl_lib.h at line 1799 saying next to it "__position: 0 __args#0: var-create: unable to create var object" while highlighting line 1801.

Can't see where is the error in my code. Help please.

Comment: What is SPLITaVecINT? Can you send a reproducible code?

Comment: The message seems to be a known bug in gdb and is unrelated to your bug. Please create a [mcve].